# Company Wide Windows Auth with Chrome and Firefox

Tags: group-policy, kerberos, firefox, windows-authentication, google-chrome

I know that we can allow Firefox to allow passing through of Windows credentials by editing the following about:config settings

```
--If using Kerberos--
network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris
network.negotiate-auth.delegation-uris

--If using NTLM--
network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris
```

and in Chrome by adding a command line switch

```
-–auth-negotiate-delegate-whitelist="*example.com"
```

However, these are both difficult to manage in a company wide setting. Does anyone have any good solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure of your environment setup, but this can be handled with Group Policies.  Chrome and Chromium both support the AuthServerWhitelist from GPO.

More information and a template for Chrome GPO's can be found here: http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3